# refresh RecyclerView from another Activity After add a value

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a `MainActivity` with tabhost , `tabhost` has three tab(`Fragment`) . SecondTab has a `RecyclerView` . In `MainActivity`, use the ActionBar button to go to another activity(NewClass) and add new values(MainActivity is still open) . After adding new values, I want to go back to `MainActivity` and refresh the `RecyclerView` to display new values.
I am using reactToPublishedEvent() method to refresh RecyclerView but doesnt work.
I could not solve my problem with using answers  .

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Publisher{
private Listener listener;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//. . .

public void onClick(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    intent.setClass(this , NewClass.class);

    startActivityForResult(intent , 1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        if(data != null)
        {
             listener.reactToPublishedEvent();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void setListener(SecondTab listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

interface Listener{
    void reactToPublishedEvent();
}}
```

**NewClass**

```
boolean check = database.SaveClass(className, classDay, classTimeStart, classTimeEnd, Integer.parseInt(classNumber), uniName , checkMidTerm , checkEndTerm , checkPractical , checkProject , checkConference);

if(check)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    setResult(RESULT_OK , intent);

    finish();
}
```

**SecondTab :**

```
public class SecondTab extends Fragment implements MainActivity.Listener{

private RecyclerView recyclerView;

private DatabaseHandler database;

private RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerAdapter;

private List<ClassTable> classData;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_second_tab, container, false);

    database = new DatabaseHandler(getContext());

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_SecondTab);

    classData = new ArrayList<>();

    prepareAdapter();

    return view;
}

private void prepareAdapter()
{
    classData = database.getClassData();//Receive table data

    recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this , getContext(), classData);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
}

    @Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    if(context instanceof Publisher){
        ((Publisher)context).setListener(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void reactToPublishedEvent() {
    recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//this line is not correct
}
```

**Publisher**

```
public interface Publisher {
void setListener(SecondTab listener);}
```

Comment: want to pass data NewClass to MainActivity?

Comment: no i want to after return to MainActivity , refresh RecyclerView but recyclerView is in another fragment and i dont have any access to that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use Publisher/Listener pattern.
Publisher - publish some event. Listener react to this events.

So you need to create two interfaces:

```
interface Publisher{
void setListener(Listener listener)
}
```

And

```
interface Listener{
void reactToPublishedEvent()
}
```

Your MainActivity is publisher. It emmit some events, so your MainActivity should be updated:

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Publisher{
private Listener listener;
... // Some your code here

@Ovveride
public void setListener(Listener listener){
this.listener = listener
}
}
```

Your SecondTab is Listener and should be updated as:

```
public class SecondTab extends Fragment implements AlertDialogShowClass.OnItemChange, Listener{
... //Your code here
@Ovveride
public void onAttach(Context context){
//Set this fragment in activity as Listener
if(context instance of Publisher){
    ((Publisher)context).setListener(this)
}
}
}
```

Then in onActivityResult method you can write something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        if(data != null && listener!=null)
        {
             listener.reactToPublishedEvent()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i edit post , What is the shortest way to this you think?

Comment: You need to make changes in your reactToPublishedEvent() method. Provide data, which should be updated in recyclerview through this method as parameters. It should be like reactToPubluishedEvent(List<YourClass) data)

And then set this data into adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged(). This is the shortest way

Answer (score 0):

There are two way

1.Local broadcast manager

2.Interface

Comment: how to use interface  ? can you take an example

Comment: Are you get successfully callback in MainActivity by onActivityResult?

Comment: yes , i want to refresh recyclerView in onActivityResult

Answer (score 0):

Few methods to achieve the problem.

1. Observer Pattern.
2. Local BroadcastManager.
3. Directly update from the Fragment.

First and second methods are already described in above answers. So will describe the the third one.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        if(data != null)
        {
            Fragment fragment  = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
            if (fragment instanceof SecondTab)
            {
                 ((SecondTab)fragment).recyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 // Any Notify method as the requirement
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope This will help.
Cheers!!

Comment: i change this line to `((SecondTab)fragment).recyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();` to `((SecondTab)fragment).recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();` but but does not

Comment: @NimaKhalili Please check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54770162/3467187